# fail to git clone my repository from Bitbucket through ssh

Tags: git, bitbucket

I want to clone repository into local directory from remote repository and report error. I have no idea how to figure out it.
Error : 'D:/test/.git/refs/heads/"main".lock': Invalid argument.

Firstly, I create ssh key and copy public key onto my Bitbucket account.
Secondly i execute command : git clone git@bitbucket.org:myprject/myrepo.git.
Then report fatal error:
fatal: update_ref failed for ref 'HEAD': cannot lock ref 'HEAD': Unable to create 'D:/test/.git/refs/heads/"main".lock': Invalid argument.
Any idea about this error?

Comment: What's the name of the default branch? Is it `main` or `"main"`?